# Remove Multiple Folders/Files From Remote Repo

Tags: git, gitlab, repository

Currently doing a clean-up in our repositories, I'm trying to remove unnecessary folders/files from the repo, tried researching and saw solutions like git filter branch but this command is just for a single file/folder and takes time. Is there a way I can remove multiple folders/files from our repo in just a single command because these are hundred of files/folders

Answer (score 1):

The `rm -r` command will recursively remove your folder:

```
git rm -r folder-name
```

And for files:

If you want to remove the file from the Git `repo` and `filesystem`, use:

```
git rm some_file.txt
git commit -m "remove some_file.txt"
```

But if you want to remove the file only from the Git repo:

```
git rm --cached some_file.txt
git commit -m "remove some_file.txt"
```